# Backlight control broken on 14.04 on Lenovo U310

Tags: 14.04, laptop, brightness, backlight

I'm unable to change the backlight brightness under 14.04.

```
habefaro@habefaro-Lenovo-U310:~$ uname -a
Linux habefaro-Lenovo-U310 3.16.0-34-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 17:49:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using the keys or xbacklight results in changing the values reported by xbacklight or /sys/

```
habefaro@habefaro-Lenovo-U310:~$ xbacklight
19.991807
habefaro@habefaro-Lenovo-U310:~$ xbacklight -dec 40
habefaro@habefaro-Lenovo-U310:~$ xbacklight
0.000000
```

Before pressing brightness keys:

```
habefaro@habefaro-Lenovo-U310:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
0
```

After "increasing" the brightness:

```
habefaro@habefaro-Lenovo-U310:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
1464
```

The actual brightness of the screen however stays the same. It has been suggested to use

```
 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor
```

as boot options, but to no avail.